# Neither netflix-desktop nor Chrome will load and run properly

Tags: software-installation

Installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 from live DVD. Performed all the post-installation steps according to [this howtoubuntu guide](http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-10-utopic-unicorn).

Installed Chrome as the guide suggested, launched through the search function - process seemed to go well, but Chrome does not appear to be working at all. It doesn't open!

Same with the netflix-desktop application, which works well on Linux Mint.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, countless people here run Netflix on Chrome in Ubuntu, so I don't think these claims are false. Rather than guessing what is wrong, perhaps we can help you if you tell us what happens if you run Chrome from the terminal. Do you see any error messages? Also I can't help noticing that you followed the wrong howtoubuntu guide: you should have followed [this](http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr) instead.

Comment: If you do not want people to guess, you will have to provide enough information and a direct question which can be answered.

Comment: Ubuntu works fine. On one laptop I tried it on. The machine I'm trying to get working is an IBM T61 with external monitor only. Problem is with Chrome's vodeo output. Ubuntu output is fine and works well on the setup. Launching Chrome, I believe it is looking for the T61 LCD screen and ignores the external monitor. Any suggestions?

Comment: Forgive me for my acidic remarks, frustration looms. @ Jos - I believe I did use the procedure you pointed to in setting up the machine that does work. I will reload a fresh install on my Frankenpad and try it again.  Thanks guys for help

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. Went into BIOS on the T61 and set video output to VGA/DVI only. Rebooted. Went to **Settings > Display** and deactivated the internal monitor and used the external to launch from. Bingo! :-)